# How to Use FFMPEG in inside the Delphi

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg, delphi-7

Iam beginner in delphi.i create the one sample application i need one help.how to use FFMPEG in inside the delphi?

Comment: I can't see whats wrong with this question

Comment: same for me, perfectly valid as I'm searching for same information

Answer (score 5):

FFMPEG is a command line app, so you can easily call it using `ShellExecute()`, with some examples [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm).

First, however, you need to decide what command line switches to use.

I can post code tomorrow if you need further help.

EDIT:

Here is a more advanced method to run a command line application: It redirects the output to a memo for viewing:

```
procedure GetDosOutput(CommandLine, WorkDir: string;aMemo : TMemo);
var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  WasOK: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  Handle: Boolean;
begin
  AMemo.Lines.Add('Commencing processing...');
  with SA do begin
    nLength := SizeOf(SA);
    bInheritHandle := True;
    lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  end;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);
  try
    with SI do
    begin
      FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
      cb := SizeOf(SI);
      dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
      wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
      hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // don't redirect stdin
      hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
      hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
    end;
    Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CommandLine),
                            nil, nil, True, 0, nil,
                            PChar(WorkDir), SI, PI);
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
    if Handle then
      try
        repeat
          WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255, BytesRead, nil);
          if BytesRead > 0 then
          begin
            Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
            AMemo.Text := AMemo.Text + Buffer;
          end;
        until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
    AMemo.Lines.Add('Processing completed successfully.');
    AMemo.Lines.Add('**********************************');
    AMemo.Lines.Add('');
  end;
end;
```

It can be called like so:

```
cmd := 'ffmpeg.exe -i "'+InFile+'" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "'+OutFile+'"';
GetDosOutput(cmd,FFMPEGDirectory,MemoLog);
```

Comment: hi simon , can u give any example

Answer (score 1):

Here is the encapsulated library of FFmpeg for Delphi.

http://www.delphiffmpeg.com/

You may read the documents and try to build the examples.